# Angular combining Http Get response with conditional http post

Tags: angular

I am implementing a private message system in an app that uses angular 4.  When a user clicks on a unread message in their inbox (that may make up one of multiple messages in a thread that also may be unread) all the messages should be returned in the thread but I also want to check to see if any of the messages are unread, and mark them as read as part of this method.

The call to get the messages looks as follows:

```
getMessageThread(id: number, recipientId: number) {
  return this.authHttp.get(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + id + '/messages/' + recipientId)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and in the component:

```
loadMessageThread() {
    const currentUserId = +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid;
    this.userService.getMessageThread(currentUserId, this.userId).subscribe(messages => {
      this.messages = messages;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
  });
}
```

I also have the following method in the service which should be called conditionally if any of the returned messages in the thread are marked as unread:

```
markAsRead(userId: number, messageId: number) {
  return this.authHttp.post(this.baseUrl + 'users/' + userId + '/messages/' + messageId, {}).subscribe();
}
```

So far I have tried a few different options.  If I try and call the user service from within the subscribe I get an error stating the user service is undefined:

```
loadMessageThread() {
  const currentUserId = +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid;
  this.userService.getMessageThread(currentUserId, this.userId)
    .subscribe(messages => {
      this.messages = messages;
      _.each(this.messages, function(message) {
        if (message.read === false && message.recipientId === currentUserId) {
          console.log(message) // works
      this.userService.markAsRead(currentUserId, message.id); // fails
      }
    });
  }, error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  });
}
```

If I try using a 'do' method prior to the subscribe this also fails to call the method in the service and goes straight to the error condition without hitting the subscribe method:

```
  loadMessageThread() {
const currentUserId = +this.authService.decodedToken.nameid;
this.userService.getMessageThread(currentUserId, this.userId)
  .do(messages => {
    _.each(messages, function (message: IMessage) {
      if (message.read === false && message.recipientId === currentUserId) {
    console.log(message) // works
        this.userService.markAsRead(currentUserId, message.id); // fails
      }
    });
  })
  .subscribe(messages => {
    this.messages = messages;
  }, error => {
    this.alertify.error(error);
  });
}
```

I'm not sure if I am overthinking this and am missing a more obvious approach to this.  Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks, Neil

Comment: It looks like you're trying to chain Observables. Have a look at RxJs' `mergeMap()` method to achieve it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239552/angular-2-chain-observables-in-resolver) might also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 _.each(this.messages, function (message) {
```

should be

```
 _.each(this.messages, (message) => {
```

otherwise `this` will not refer to the component.